# Looping through videos from a very large channel on YouTube?

Tags: php, youtube, zend-gdata

I'm currently using **ZendGData** to get **video IDs** from channels on **youtube**. However, when the channel is quite **large**, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 
46 bytes)
```

If I could, I wouldn't use the library but I can't find a way to **display all the videos** from a channel on a **single page** (they're using Ajax to load more videos when you request it via a button). This would be the best because I could simply strip some tags to get IDs.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please show the code you're using to load and display videos.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Pagination

I'm using the code shown there and in the foreach loop, I'm adding the video ID to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP runs out of memory since you're creating loads and loads of objects. What worked for me was setting the PHP memory limit to infinite. You can do this either in your php.ini or with ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');